# Is there a way I can simplify removal of an object from my dbset with EF6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I was previously using a repository with this code:

```
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
```

My application is simple and I noticed many people saying "EF is already a repository so you don't need to use another one". The problem is that without that external repository wrapping I now find that when I want to code a simple delete I find it's necessary to do something like this:

```
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry1 = db.Entry(objectiveDetail);
    if (dbEntityEntry1.State != EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        dbEntityEntry1.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    else
    {
        db.ObjectiveDetails.Attach(objectiveDetail);
        db.ObjectiveDetails.Remove(objectiveDetail);
    }
```

My one line repo.delete has now changed to ten lines.  Is there a way I can get back to simplifying the removal of an entry with EF without having to hard code all the lines for checking if the entry is already attached etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, although EF is a repository in and of itself, it still makes sense in many situations from a separation of concerns perspective to abstract EF out and use a Repository pattern to achieve this.  I use a repository pattern quite often with EF.  If you are using automated unit tests, the repository pattern makes isolating your code for testing much easier.